# finding a class object by its methods or atributes.Could it be done?

Tags: python, database, class, for-loop, if-statement

```
class Mushroom:
    def __init__(self,name,color_cap,color_gills,scales,poisenous):
        self.name = name
        self.color_cap = color_cap
        self.color_gills = color_gills
        self.scales = scales
        self.poisenous = poisenous

    def is_poisonous(self):
        if self.poisenous == "Poisonous":
            print("This Mushroom is poisonous")
        else:
            print("This Mushroom can be eaten")

amanita_muscaria=Mushroom("Chervena muhomorka","Red","White",True,"Poisonous")
print(amanita_muscaria.eate)
```

My question is exacly how i can get the program to print if the mushroom is poisonous or it can be eaten.Maybe a for loop will be better.I want my final product to be a database with mushrooms where the user inputs a name,cap color,gills color and scales to get printed all the mushrooms in the database/txt.file that have the same attributes and to tell him if the mushroom is poisenous or not

Comment: Isn't this what `is_poisonous` currently does?

Comment: You can access class attributes directly, as in `print(amanita_muscaria.poisenous)` but beyond that it's not entirely clear what you're trying to do. One thing you might consider for the attribute is making it boolean instead of a string field, so that you can do `if amanita_muscaria.poisenous == True:...` comparisons